# Router and NAS on same server

Tags: networking, server, router

I got a Ubuntu Server that run smb, transmission-daemon and DNS. In my home we are 9 people, with a total of 16 devices connected to the network.

**List of "hardware"**

- 100Mbit line in
- Standard modem from ISP
- 2x N600 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router
- Dumb gigabit switch (Not in use now)

Right now i have connected it like this:
line in -> modem -> router -> router.
In "prime time" we got some spikes on the network (this is on both cable and wlan). On a daily base we in total download/upload 22GB a day.

I was wondering if I can set up my server with two more network cards, and set up those as router, then my network would look like this:

line in -> modem -> Server router -> switch -> 2x router.

TLDR: How to set up Ubuntu server with 3 network cards, 1 for local server, 2 for Router.

I think the spikes comes from the poor router that is the connected to the modem.

Comment: The bottleneck of the ISP modem.  You should only need one router.  What is the ISP modem? (cable, ADSL2+, etc.) What is the '2x router'? (a brand/model, or two identical routers?)  This should work just fine with: **line in -> modem -> router (w/ dual-band WiFi) -> Gigabit switch -> server, other Ethernet devices**

Comment: I doubt it is the ISP modem, i get 100mbit with it. Like i wrote in the post, the wlan routers are: N600 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router. You can't meen that I should have 1 home wlan ap for 16 devices?

Comment: No. I needed clarity that you meant **two** identical WiFi routers.  You just need to disable one as *router*, and attach it to either the first router or Gigabit switch (based on whether there is a spare port on the first router).

Comment: Its to identical wifi routers. The network is up and running now, but i get spikes. Like the post sais, I have connected one router to the other:

line in-> modem-> router -> router